# Find to which git commit a file belongs?

Tags: git

Given a random file, is there a canonical method to determine from the command line whether the file belongs to a particular commit?

This is similar to stack overflow question [find-out-which-git-commit-a-file-was-taken-from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426506/find-out-which-git-commit-a-file-was-taken-from) except that I wish to be able to use it in scripts and also not create a temporary branch.

Comment: @Bryce the reason I ask is that (with git) I always suspect there is some command like "git ls-tree --do-something-magical that does exactly what I want. Like when I discovered "git hash-object" minutes after writing a handy git sha-1 calculator in Python!

Comment: An example would be when someone sends a configuration file (retrieved from hardware) up the support tiers until it is handed off for a post mortem or diagnosis. What commit or release did it come from? In the wayback days, we used RCS (and eventually CVS) keyword expansion for this purpose. I am pretty sure we could use commit and checkout hooks to add fake keyword expansion, but it is such a kludge that I am a bit embarrassed to even mention it.

Comment: The link suggests, and it's clear from your 2nd comment, that you're talking about a file that is not part of your working tree -- but the question itself doesn't say that. It sounds like you're just asking for `git log -1 -- $filename` (possibly with some confusion over the meaning of "belong"). Can you rephrase it a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an excerpt of a script that I have been using for the purpose. I hacked it together using my limited git knowledge and pieces of other scripts that I have found on the web. It works well enough, but I often find that there are easier ways to do things in git than what I have learned by trial and error.

```
FILE=$1

# git hash for file
HASH=`git hash-object $FILE`

# git revisions for file
REVS=`git log --pretty=%H -- $FILE`

# check each revision for checksum match
for rev in $REVS; do
    POSSIBLE=`git ls-tree $rev $FILE | awk '{print $3}'`
    if [[ $HASH == $POSSIBLE ]]; then
        echo $rev
    fi
done
```

Comment: Other than changing `git log --pretty=...` to `git rev-list --all -- $FILE` I would not change anything about your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, was the file modified in a commit? If so, something like `git log --oneline -- filePathName` should list the commits from HEAD where that is the case.

On second reading, I think you are just asking for commits which contain that file, whether or not its changed. If so, then doesn't your ls-tree need a -r flag, to recurse into its sub-trees (subdirs)? that will find any copies of a file under any name, if you just match on the sha.

Comment: That appears to return all commits involving that file name - but not the specific commit that contains the file in the exact state that it is in at the moment.

Comment: ah, ok, so you are looking for an exact match of that file. So still, shouldnt you be recursing (above) and looking for a match of each of the blob's shas with the sha of the file you are trying to match to?

Answer (score 1):

[Your approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38622426/6394138) may fail to work in case of insignificant differences (e.g. line-ending style, or differences due to clean/smudge filters) between the local and repository versions of the file.

The following script works via `git diff` rather than relying on hashes. It accepts diff options after the file name.

**Usage examples:**

```
# list all commits that introduce the file README.md in its local state
list_introducing_commits README.md

# list all commits that introduce the file README.md in its local state
# ignoring any difference in whitespace
list_introducing_commits README.md -w
```

**list_introducing_commits** (couldn't find a better name):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) path/to/file [<diff-options>]"
    exit 1
fi

file="$1"
shift 1

for rev in $(git log --pretty=%H -- "$file")
do
    if git diff --exit-code $@ $rev -- $file &> /dev/null
    then
        echo $rev
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [DavidN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640243/davidn)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38621861/5819286), if the file is in the current worktree, and the worktree is in sync with HEAD, this will get you the commit corresponding to the file's current contents:

```
git log --pretty="%H" -1  -- path/to/file
```

But you might want to test those assumptions ahead of time via "`git diff --exit-code /path/to/file`" and taking a peek at `$?`.